# Is there a way to take a unique string of 256 chars, reduce it's size with JS to a unique string of 50± chars, and retain guaranteed uniqueness?

Tags: javascript, compression

I am working on building a parser for a text file to build into a JSON object.

Presuming I have a string somewhere in the line which is a unique value: `4E183437F3FAEBC107C333CD16657661598A2A523867A4A95F6DAD4D25E191722AFFB3FFE29E287D9EB21ED8035E7666D06E65EC064D5D4B337C034459BA7CD6F72437B439329B45F15D57176122965728B36DBB455D335AA904106A29B64694507B6A0F89FBF4A166BB3BBB4DDDC1674A1DB3B7D0FD332117877C4CE56465D8`

I want to use this unique identifier as a `key` at some level, but it's much too long to suit my tastes.

I am wondering if there is a way to create a smaller 'hash':

1. but not lose and information
2. guarantee uniqueness
3. be converted back to it's original

Some library/plugin?

Comment: those 256 characters are hexadecimal, so each character represents 4 bits - i.e. you have 1024 bits ... with 8 bits per character, you'd end up with 128 characters ... so, no way to get to 50

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *string* of smaller length by turning the 16-bit hex string into a number (with BigInt), and then by creating a new string with base, say, 10000, so that a character with character code C represents the number `'C'.charCodeAt()`.

Then turn it back into the original string by doing the same process in reverse.

The string length is shorter, and you've saved *some* bits, but it's still long:

```js
const encode = (input) => {
  let n = 0n;
  [...input].forEach((char, i) => {
    const code = char.charCodeAt();
    const value = BigInt(code <= 57 ? code - 48 : code - 55);
    n += value * (16n ** BigInt(i));
  });
  const base10Str = String(n);
  let output = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < base10Str.length; i += 4) {
    output += String.fromCharCode(base10Str.slice(i, i + 4));
  }
  return output;
};

const decode = (encoded) => {
  let base10Str = '';
  [...encoded].forEach((char) => {
    base10Str += String(char.charCodeAt()).padStart(4, '0'); // todo: final char may need no padding
  });
  let n = BigInt(base10Str);
  let inputStr = '';
  for (let i = 255; i >= 0; i--) {
    const thisHexMult = 16n ** BigInt(i);
    const thisHexDigitBigInt = n / thisHexMult; // This will automatically effectively call Math.floor
    n = n % thisHexMult;
    const thisHexDigit = Number(thisHexDigitBigInt);
    const charCode = thisHexDigit <= 9 ? thisHexDigit + 48 : thisHexDigit + 55;
    inputStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode) + inputStr;
  }
  console.log(inputStr);
};

const encoded = encode('4E183437F3FAEBC107C333CD16657661598A2A523867A4A95F6DAD4D25E191722AFFB3FFE29E287D9EB21ED8035E7666D06E65EC064D5D4B337C034459BA7CD6F72437B439329B45F15D57176122965728B36DBB455D335AA904106A29B64694507B6A0F89FBF4A166BB3BBB4DDDC1674A1DB3B7D0FD332117877C4CE56465D8');

console.log('Encoded length:', encoded.length);
console.log(encoded);

decode(encoded);
```